# Nested dict throws key error when sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have below dict called `nested`:

```
{1: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 3: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'x0': Decimal('279.552')},
     3: {'x0': Decimal('290.868')}},
 4: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 5: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 6: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 7: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('256.896')}},
 8: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'x0': Decimal('232.307')},
     3: {'x0': Decimal('244.550')},
     4: {'x0': Decimal('253.296')}},
 9: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'x0': Decimal('277.219')},
     3: {'x0': Decimal('288.064')}},
 10: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('255.648')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('281.909')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('288.314')}},
 11: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('259.712')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('295.884')}},
 12: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('288.064')}},
 13: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('273.152')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('299.412')}},
 14: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('259.712')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('295.884')}},
 15: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 16: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('246.303')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('272.564')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('278.969')}},
 17: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 18: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 19: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('249.746')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('260.590')}},
 20: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('239.300')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('265.560')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('271.965')},
      5: {'x0': Decimal('294.708')}},
 21: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 22: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 23: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 24: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('273.152')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('299.412')}},
 25: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('260.868')}},
 26: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('249.746')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('260.590')}},
 27: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('246.303')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('272.564')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('278.969')},
      5: {'x0': Decimal('298.215')}},
 28: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 29: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 30: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('295.596')}}
```

That I am trying to sort by the `x0` value inside each nested dictionary.

I only want to sort the "inner" values, so for my specific example:

```
{1: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 [...]
```

I am trying to sort it using `sorted()` method:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(nested.values(), key=lambda x: x['x0'])
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: 'x0'
```

As you can see, inside `2`, the nested dict is sorted.

## Edit

To clarify, my dict actually contains another key:

```
{1: {1: {'text': 'Hi there!', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My email is', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'text': 'example@domain.com', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 [...]
```

When implementing the solution from @Willem, only the `x0` is being sorted, but the `text` key is not being sorted along with it:

```
{1: {1: {'text': 'Hi there!', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'My email is', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
     2: {'text': 'example@domain.com', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 [...]
```

Comment: A warning: Dictionaries in Python only have a well defined order (insertion order) in Python 3.7. In earlier versions, the order a dictionary would iterate in was implementation defined, and so might vary between interpreters or between versions of the same interpreter (or even invocations of the same interpreter, for some kinds of keys, if hash randomization is enabled). If you want to deal with ordered data in a backwards compatible way, you will probably want to be using lists or tuples.

Comment: @Blckknght: If I understood it correctly the values are remapped to different keys, so in the original data the dictionary was first associated with key `2`, and now with key `1`. I agree however that a list would make more sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x0` key is defined in the *subdictionaries*. So you can not sort it by using `sorted(..)` on the outer values.

You can construct a dictionary like:

```
from operator import itemgetter

{k : dict(enumerate(sorted(v.values(), key=itemgetter('x0')), 1))
 for k, v in nested.items() }
```

We here make the assumption that the keys of the subdictionaries have keys `1`, `2`, ... It might however make more sense to use lists instead of dictionaries of the keys are increasing that way.

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
{1: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 3: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'x0': Decimal('279.552')},
     3: {'x0': Decimal('290.868')}},
 4: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 5: {1: {'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 6: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 7: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('256.896')}},
 8: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'x0': Decimal('232.307')},
     3: {'x0': Decimal('244.550')},
     4: {'x0': Decimal('253.296')}},
 9: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
     2: {'x0': Decimal('277.219')},
     3: {'x0': Decimal('288.064')}},
 10: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('255.648')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('281.909')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('288.314')}},
 11: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('259.712')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('295.884')}},
 12: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('288.064')}},
 13: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('273.152')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('299.412')}},
 14: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('259.712')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('295.884')}},
 15: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 16: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('246.303')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('272.564')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('278.969')}},
 17: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 18: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 19: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('249.746')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('260.590')}},
 20: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('239.300')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('265.560')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('271.965')},
      5: {'x0': Decimal('294.708')}},
 21: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 22: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 23: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 24: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('273.152')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('299.412')}},
 25: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('260.868')}},
 26: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('249.746')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('260.590')}},
 27: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
      2: {'x0': Decimal('246.303')},
      3: {'x0': Decimal('272.564')},
      4: {'x0': Decimal('278.969')},
      5: {'x0': Decimal('298.215')}},
 28: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 29: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}},
 30: {1: {'x0': Decimal('223.560')}, 2: {'x0': Decimal('295.596')}}}
```

or with an extra `'text'` key:

```
{1: {1: {'text': 'Hi there!', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}},
 2: {1: {'text': 'example@domain.com', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
     2: {'text': 'My email is', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')}}}
```

Comment: Very nice solution - I tried it, and it does work with the key `x0` - however, the nested dict also contains a `text` key. I supposed that as long as the nested dict got sortefd, all key/values inside that dict would get sorted as well. Would you mind seeing my updated question, as I have made an edit?

Comment: @oliverbj: I'm not entirely sure if there is a `text` attribute that this makes much sense, since before Python-3.6, dictionaries were unordered (and it might be better to still consider these conceptually unordered).

Comment: What would be another solution then? To change it to a nested list/tuple? Would that make it possible to sort the way I am looking for?

Comment: @oliverbj: furthermore if I understood it correctly, the `text` is actually sorted along with it. See update, as you can see, the `'example@domain.com` is still associated with `21.600`, but it is now placed first.

Comment: It must be that I am printing out the wrong information. Apologize, but how do I print the new sorted dict? `{k : dict(...)`

Comment: I figured it out.. Just give it a variable name `name = {k: dict(...)` Thanks!! :)